# Docker Like DB Deployment

Tags: sql-server, windows, docker

I've just finished setting a dev environment where every developers /feature/*, /bugfix/* and /hotfix/* git branches are automatically built and deployed to a freshly provisioned Windows Container which hosts the webapp and services creating a test environment, for each branch to be validated before merging into master.

While this is working quite nicely, I've still only got 1 dev db per developer which is used by all of their branches.

In an ideal world, I would like each of these test containers to use their own isolated db instance, however the db is currently at about 50gb at the smallest i can get it without going and tearing out historical data which is sometime useful.

What I would really like to do, is create a docker like image for this db and then spawn a new "container" from this image which only keeps track of the diff between it's changes an the original without ever altering the original db.

Is something like this even possible or does anyone have any ideas how I might achieve this db isolation, per container without having to create a full 50gb db for each?

Comment: Even if you had Docker, how would you deploy the  *data in the database*? That's the part that Docker can't handle nor does it try to - managing the data. You can use database snapshots, and/or differential backups/restores to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So after much flailing around in the dark, I think I've finally come up with a solution. @ErikEJ, thanks, you started me off in the right direction. After looking into DB Snapshots on MSSQL, I found the only way to do writable snapshots seemed to be using vss and actually creating writable disk snapshots. This too led me down a long path of at first trying locally and failing, then trying to implement iscsi and still getting nowhere. Then I stumbled upon hyper-v snapshots and had a look at what was happening under the hood there and finally came across creating differencing VHD's. So basically my solution is as below.

Create VHD with a sanitised copy of my production DB mdf and ldf file in.
Then I create differencing vhds for each environment I need, mount the differencing vhds each in their own folder eg c:\db\Issue-1234 and create a new db DB_ISSUE-1234 by atatching to the files in these folders. Only the diffs are then stored and instead of having several 50-60gig copies of the db. I only have 1 and then the differencing vhds only store the difference.

I've just got this working with 2 or 3, so not sure how robust it is and how fast these differencing vhds are going to grow, but looking very promising so far and is allowing me to spin up multiple environments  for testing purposes, extremely quickly (in fact all automated by scripts in deployment).

Hope this possibly helps someone else save some time one day and please let me know if anyone has figured out a more efficient/quicker/better way to do this :)